# Associating an Uploaded Image File with Existing Album

Tags: php, mysql, image

I am relatively new to PHP/MySQL and have been having a problem that I cannot figure out. I've scoured this site but cannot find any information.

My problem is very simple: How to associate an uploaded image file with a pre-existing album.

I have 2 separate tables in my database:  one for albums and one for images. What I want to do is have an `<option>` drop down menu retrieving the user's pre-existing albums thus assigning an `albumID` to the image database.

I have successfully populated a drop down box with the user's albums, but cannot figure out how to insert the selected ID into the picture table `albumid`.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to SO! What is that you have problems with? Figuring out what your form should send to the back-end? Or is the problem more about how to associate the uploaded file with the right album in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you selectd album from drop down, you could reload the page, adding the album ID in the URL. Then you only need to use `$_GET` to get the album id.

Then, when you upload the image, in your `upload.php` file, you use the `$_GET` to retrieve the album ID.

Once you have successfully moved the image from the upload temp directory to it's final location, add the image URL to the image table and retrieve last inserted row ID. Take this ID and insert it into album table.

Does that answer your question? :)

Comment: It makes total sense and works perfectly. I cannot believe it was just a simple $_GET that I was overlooking. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Matthew, no problem. Just remember to mark the answer as `accepted` if it solved your problem - and maybe arrow up if you foudn the answer usefull :)

Answer (score 0):

Say you have album1, in picture table you would use the following :

```
UPDATE picturetable SET albumid = 'album1' WHERE ID = 'the_picture_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, Assuming that you have the file Upload working correctly and have no problem inserting the relevant picture data into the picture table:

```
<form method="post" enc-type="multipart/form-data">
    <select name="Albums">
        <option value="1">My First Album</option>
        <option value="2">My Secret Album of Dirty Pictures</option>
    </select>

    <input type="file" name="MyFile" />
</form>
```

in your code you would get the id of the selected album from the POST variables in the following manner, similar to how you accessed the file upload information. Then you input it all into your mysql table at the same time.

```
<?php 

     $AlbumId = $_POST["Albums"];
     $Picture = $_FILES["MyFile"]["name"];

     $Sql = "INSERT INTO Pictures (AlbumId, Picture) VALUES ($AlbumId, '$Picture')";
     mysql_query($Sql);
?>
```

Comment: @Johan, I think Goblyn27 just provided code without any checking to demonstrate a possible solution. No point in downvoting. Just comment the fact that one has to check for SQL injection as well.